# Select another column value from the same table if another column value is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, coalesce

I have a table with four columns: `NAME`, `AGE`, `PRIMARYWEIGHT` and `SECONDARYWEIGHT`

`Where NAME = 'Damian'`, I wish to select `AGE` and `PRIMARYWEIGHT` only if `SECONDARYWEIGHT` is `NULL` otherwise I'll take `PRIMARYWEIGHT`.

Ideally I'd like to give its an alias 'WEIGHT' regardless of whether it was `PRIMARYWEIGHT` or `SECONDARYWEIGHT`.

Comment: please show expected output and input in the form of text

Comment: sql server has an isNull function.

Comment: You have the answer in your tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT NAME, AGE, ISNULL(PRIMARYWEIGHT, SECONDARYWEIGH) As WEIGHT
```

[msdn reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

Comment: _"I wish to select AGE and PRIMARYWEIGHT only ...  otherwise l take PRIMARYWEIGHT"_ Shouldn't be the `Age` excluded if `SECONDARYWEIGHT` is not null?

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this as soon as I am able to. I saw ISNULL but wasn't sure it would work for SQL server 2008.

Comment: @Tim my bad, Josh is right. I still wish to obtain AGE regardless. NAME I do not need as I provided it during my WHERE clause

Comment: @TobyDerrum you can use [`isnull()` - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) or [`coalesce()` - msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx). Assuming there is no conflict between data types.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT AGE, COALESCE(SECONDARYWEIGH, PRIMARYWEIGHT) As WEIGHT
```

You can use [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) (*as indicated in your tag*)

> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.